# trying to force static object initialization

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, static-members

I am trying to initialize a static object without success. The purpose is to automatically register a factory class in a repository (which is a singleton).

I've already had a look at: [How to force a static member to be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420985/how-to-force-a-static-member-to-be-initialized)

One of the comments says that (there is also an example that I've followed):

> I read it up in the C++ standard (14.7.1): Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

So I'm trying to do something similar but I haven't manage to force the object initialization. Here is the code. I don't know what I'm missing. This is the template I'm using.

```
namespace my_lib
{
    template <typename T>
    struct FactoryHelper
    {
        FactoryHelper ();
        static FactoryHelper<T> _helper;
    };
}
```

And this is the macro that the user of the library would use to define the factory class and, at the same time, register an object in the repository:

```
#define CREATE_FACTORY(ClassName)\
namespace my_lib\
{\
    class ClassName##Factory;\
    template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::FactoryHelper () { std::cout << "object initialized!" << std::endl; }\
    template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::_helper;\
    struct ClassName##Factory : public FactoryBase<ClassName> {\
      ...\
    };\
}
```

The previous code is defined in a header file (Factory.h).

In a .cpp file (Example.cpp), I have:

```
CREATE_FACTORY(UnitTestExample)
...
```

When I execute the program, I cannot see the message that the constructor prints when it is invoked. Any help is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tricky area of C++.   What you've done is to try to define the static member here:

```
template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::_helper;\
```

but this is actually a declaration and not a definition.  For C++ to treat it as a definition you have to pass something to the constructor.  Typically, this is the value you want to initialize it to:

```
template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::_helper = FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>();\
```

But in your case, you want this to be a singleton, so you probably don't want it to be copyable.  In that case, you need some dummy parameter:

```
template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::_helper(0);\
```

and you have to modify your constructor appropriately:

```
template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::FactoryHelper (int) { std::cout << "object initialized!" << std::endl; }\
```

Here is the complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace my_lib
{
    template<typename> struct FactoryBase { };
    template <typename T>
    struct FactoryHelper
    {
        FactoryHelper (int);
        static FactoryHelper<T> _helper;
    };
}

#define CREATE_FACTORY(ClassName)\
namespace my_lib\
{\
    class ClassName##Factory;\
    template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::FactoryHelper (int) { std::cout << "object initialized!" << std::endl; }\
    template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::_helper(0);\
    struct ClassName##Factory : public FactoryBase<ClassName> {\
    };\
} 

struct UnitTestExample {
};

CREATE_FACTORY(UnitTestExample);

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

That said, using some of the suggestions in the other answers may be a better design decision.

More information on the explicit specialization declaration vs. definition can be found here: [static member initialization for specialized template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342550/static-member-initialization-for-specialized-template-class)

Comment: Well, first of all thanks a lot for both the suggestions and the explanations. I added the solutions you gave me to the code and didn't work. Then I tried to do stand-alone programs and worked.

The difference is that the classes I'm implementing are compiled and then linked to the executable as a static library. If I compile the code all together (without using static libraries) then it works.

Why this affects to the static object initialization?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I found the response here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804606/static-initialization-and-destruction-of-a-static-librarys-globals-not-happenin

Answer (score 1):

What your macro does is to declare a specializations of some members of a class. This won't create any object and probably not what you really want anyway. What you'd need is a definition of `FactoryHelper<SomeClass>::_helper` somewhere. A definition of the static member would look something like this:

```
FactoryHelper<foo> FactoryHelper<foo>::_helper;
```

That said, I don't think the is the the way to go at all: all you really need is to instantiate something which registers a factory function and this can be done much simpler and, especially, without macros.

Here is how I would do this:

```
template <typename T>
struct factory_helper
{
    std::auto_ptr<base> create_fuction() { return std::auto_ptr<base>(new T()); }
    factory_helper(std::string const& name) {
        factory.register_class(name, create_function);
    }
};
```

This assumes that you want to create objects derived from type `base` and that your factory uses a mapping to function object returning `std::auto_ptr<base>` as constructor functions and that it has a `register_class()` function which takes the name and the constructor function as parameters. Neither of these assumptions is inherent to the apprach, though: this is just to fill in some of the blanks you didn't mention. You would register a factory function for a class `foo` something like this:

```
static factor_helper<foo> foo_helper("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a static member (you have to create somewhere), consider the possibility of a static variable into a static function, like

```
namespace my_lib
{
    template <typename T>
    struct FactoryHelper
    {
        FactoryHelper () { ... };
        static FactoryHelper<T>& helper()
        { static FactoryHelper<T> h; return h; }
    };
}
```

Not the same as you are asking, but no need of out-of-band initializations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all thanks a lot for both the suggestions and the explanations. I added the solutions you gave me to the code and didn't work. Then I tried your solutions as stand-alone programs and worked.

The difference is that the classes I'm implementing are compiled and then linked to the executable as a static libraries. If I compile the code all together (without using static libraries) then it works.

I found the response here: [Static initialization and destruction of a static library's globals not happening with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804606/static-initialization-and-destruction-of-a-static-librarys-globals-not-happenin)

The .o files are not linked unless they are referenced from the main application. I have used the `ld` option `-Wl,--whole-archive` and now it works.

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -lmy_static_library ... -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Related to the second question, I still don't understand why I have to specify a dummy parameter in the constructor.

```
template<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::_helper(0);\
```

Rather than doing this:

```
emplate<> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory> FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>::_helper = FactoryHelper<ClassName##Factory>();\
```

Thanks!

Comment: The declaration vs. definition issue is pretty tricky.  I haven't found a good explanation anywhere.  I would like to explain in more detail, but it seems somewhat beyond the scope of my original answer.

Comment: Actually, this explanation is decent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342550/static-member-initialization-for-specialized-template-class