# Technical Differences Between Shared and Static Libraries?

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

Are there any differences between the way static and shared libraries are put together?  For example, could code from a shared library be loaded into an executable at compile/link-time rather than at runtime, just like a static library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between static and shared libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any differences between the way static and shared libraries are put together?

Absolutely; they are very different animals. One major difference is that with archive library, you link in only what you use, but with shared library you get the entire thing.

> could code from a shared library be loaded into an executable at compile/link-time rather than at runtime

Not easily, but [tools](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/) do exist.

> just like a static library

I wouldn't call it "just like a static library" -- the mechanics and the end result are *very* different.