# Making a class usable to other programs

Tags: c++, class, gcc, compilation, include

I'm building an evolution simulator in C++, but not as a "real" runnable program, but rather a class that other programs should `#include`. This class, called `World`, has some functions such as `update()`, `getInfo()`, etc...

I'm facing two problems here. First off, I don't know how exactly should I compile the class, and which files should I provide the user program (the one that `#include`s the class) with. Obviously, the program should receive the `.hpp` file, but what else? An object file of the class `World`? That would imply that I'd need to compile the user program with the `g++ World.o user.o -o user` syntax, but is there a way to avoid doing that (mentioning `World.o` in my compile commands)? The same way I don't need to include `iostream.o` in the compile command.

The second problem is that the `World` class `#include`s some other classes, such as `Organism`,  which, in turn, has to include the `Block` class in order to inherit from it. How can I compile this code in order to get a single `World.o` file (if that is the answer to problem 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me that sounds like you want to make a library out of your `World` class. A library usually provides a bunch of types or functions or variables to be linked to/used by executables or other libraries.

A library is typically made up by the public *interface* and *the rest* (internals, implementation details). The former goes into the library header file, the ladder into other headers or implementation files.

The interface definition contains everything a potential user of the library needs to work with. No more, no less. That is,

- declarations of public types, functions and variables
- typedefs that are required to work with the library
- documentation
- ...

If the user only needs to interact with the `World` but not with any `Organism`, this class goes not into the library header but, for example only included into the relevant implementation files. The implementation itself may be split into different files. It's up to the linker to combine these appropriately.

---

Defining the build configuration manually can be quite a hassle when lots of files and libraries are involved. Good thing, there are tools to generate this automatically.
For example [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/). An example cmake configuration file could look like this:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

# add a shared library to build configuration
add_library(my_library_name SHARED my_library_file1.cpp my_library_file2.cpp)

# add an executable to build configuration
add_executable(my_executable_name executable_file1.cpp executable_file2.cpp)

# link the library to the executable
target_link_libraries(my_executable_name my_library_name)
```

just run `cmake` with the path to the directory where the `CMakeLists.txt` is located to build the necessary makefiles, then run `make`, then you should be done.

---

See also:

- [What is a "translation unit" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106149/1025391)
- [Difference between static and shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2649334/1025391)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a set of header files necessary for the user of your code to use.  Everything else should compile into a library for their use so that they include the set of headers into their code and link to the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can create static or shared library. http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html