# How can a library be both static and shared?

Tags: gcc, compilation, lame

What does it mean for a library to be both static and shared?  From what I've read, those two are mutually exclusive.  [People tend to define one as the opposite of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries).

But reading the configure options for LAME, I see this.

```
  $ ./configure --help
  `configure' configures lame 3.99.5 to adapt to many kinds of systems.
  [...]
  --enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=yes]
  [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What those flags do is build both shared libraries and static libraries, they don't try and make a single library both static and shared.

As you say, they are "mutually exclusive" in a sense--no single file can be both a static and shared library.

On a Linux system enabling both static and shared library compilation would give you both a *.a and a *.so file, the *.so file is used for dynamic (shared) linking, while the *.a file is used for static linking.