# Compiling libsass in Docker container

Tags: build, sass, libsass

So I have the following Dockerfile:

```
############################################################
# Based on Ubuntu
############################################################

FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER OTIS WRIGHT

# Add extra software sources

RUN apt-get update -qq

# Libsass requirements.

RUN apt-get install -y curl git build-essential automake libtool

# Fetch sources

RUN git clone https://github.com/sass/libsass.git
RUN git clone https://github.com/sass/sassc.git libsass/sassc

# Create configure script

RUN cd libsass
RUN autoreconf --force --install
RUN cd ..

# Create custom makefiles for **shared library**, for more info read:
# 'Difference between static and shared libraries?' before installing libsass  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2649334/802365

RUN cd libsass
RUN autoreconf --force --install
RUN ./configure --disable-tests --enable-shared --prefix=/usr 
RUN cd ..

# Build the library

RUN make -C libsass -j5

# Install the library

RUN make -C libsass -j5 install
```

I am trying to build `libsass` based on this gist:
https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/503d40a5c1a49cf8ae87

However when I try to build with docker I get the following error:

```
Step 11 : RUN git clone https://github.com/sass/libsass.git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d1a4eef78fa5
Step 12 : RUN git clone https://github.com/sass/sassc.git libsass/sassc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 435410579641
Step 13 : RUN cd libsass
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0a4df503d85
Step 14 : RUN autoreconf --force --install
 ---> Running in a9b0d51d6ee3
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
The command '/bin/sh -c autoreconf --force --install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I don't know a lot about compiling from source so any solutions please walk me through.

Comment: @edouardlopez : check that

Answer (score 2):

Docker won't change dirs for you `RUN cd libsass` so you need to path your commands or use the `WORKDIR` directive