# Which version of ffmpeg is newer ffmpeg-N-100679-g24dc6d386c or ffmpeg-N-4.3.1?

Tags: ffmpeg

For my app i need FFmpeg, so i went to official website, for windows builds it said go here :-
https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/tag/autobuild-2021-01-20-13-01

But now i have a problem.
Which version of ffmpeg is newer ?

`ffmpeg-N-100679` or `ffmpeg-n4.3.1-29` ?

Is that "N" version unstable and "n4" version stable ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Which is newer?

`ffmpeg-N-100679-g24dc6d386c` is newer. It is from the git master branch, and is a snapshot of the current, up-to-date FFmpeg code for the date it was released. It corresponds to commit [`24dc6d386c`](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=24dc6d386c) (note I omitted the `g` prefix) which is from 2021-01-20.

`4.3.1` is from 2020-07-11. Since new features are not backported to release versions (only certain bug fixes) it is just an extension of 4.3 which was released on 2020-06-08. The [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases) page contains the dates for releases.

So `ffmpeg-N-100679-g24dc6d386c` is about 7 months newer than 4.3.1.

## Which do I use?

- `ffmpeg-N-*` for general users. If you want the latest code and features. Required for anyone who wants to submit a bug report. If you experience a problem with the newest release. It is stable ~98% of the time I'd guess from using it over many years.
- Release version: if you are required to stay within a certain API version. For distros, distributors, users of the FFmpeg libraries, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks, one more question, Why is the statically linked version about 90mb but shared version 35mb ?         Is the shared version incomplete ? Which one is preferred for distributing with my program ?

Comment: @TanishqBanyal Despite the size difference both offer the same features in `ffmpeg`. See [Difference between static and shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries)

Answer (score 2):

Versions with `N-xxxxx` are nightly builds / snapshots and are unstable (but newer). Use them only for testing or if the last release has a bug that is already fixed and only available in the nightly.

Otherwise I recommend to use the latest release (currently 4.3.1). This is typically more stable.

Comment: Please don't do this. Always use git unless you have a specific reason to use a release. git builds are not "unstable". Statistically, they can be expected to have fewer bugs and leaks than releases.