# How to tell GCC link the library into the exe?

Tags: gcc

I am new to C and GCC. I am following [Tensorflow in C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) and I have build it successfully.

For reference, below is my GCC command

```
gcc.exe -Iinclude -Llib test.c -ltensorflow -o test.exe
```

However, when I run the exe, I am getting an error saying

```
tensorflow.dll is missing
```

and if I copy the `tensorflow.dll` on the same location as the `test.exe` it works. Is it possible to make this exe independent of the library? In other words, I want to share only the exe with others and not the library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between static and shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I saw that and I also have tensorflow.lib file with me. But dont know what is the GCC argument to do a static linking. Do you know?

Comment: Your `.lib` file is likely not a static library if it's in the same folder as the dll (see the sentence in square brackets from the accepted answer).