# Static library & Dynamic library - more C++ fun

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, dynamic-library

Let's say I want to create a dynamic library `dynamic.so`, but my code references a function that exists in some other, static library `static.a`. Naturally, if I compile and link with `g++` and the `-shared`option, `dynamic.so` will expect the referenced function to be implemented in some other dynamic library that I would have to link at runtime together with `dynamic.so`. In other words, it will be happy as long as I do `-l static` (modulo syntax).

But since that other library is actually a static one, I cannot do that. Let's assume I can not link the static library at compile time of my main program either, but I'm forced to only use dynamic libraries. So what I really want is to include the compiled code off the referenced function from `static.a` in `dynamic.so`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2649792/261142) to a related question suggests using the `--whole-archive` option to include `static.a` in `dynamic.so`. However, in my case, `static.a` is huge. And I really don't need all of it, I only need that one function definition.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246926/261142) to another question explains that linking to a static library at compile time means that only the code that is actually referenced gets included in the binary. Well, this is exactly what I would like to do for my single function reference! I don't really want the whole static archive in there.

But how can I achieve that? How can I include just the required parts of `static.a` in `dynamic.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `--whole-archive`: just link your `dynamic.so` like this:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o dynamic.so $(OBJS) -lstatic
```

This will pull into dynamic.so anything the linker needs from `libstatic.a.` See [this explanation](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) to understand why that is.

One problem might be that your `libstatic.a` is compiled without `-fPIC`. On 32-bit `x86/Linux`, that would still work (though your library will not be saving you much RAM if multiple processes are using it). On `x86_64`, linking non-fPIC code into a shared library can't work, so you'll have to rebuild it with `-fPIC`.

Comment: Awesome! Note that I mentioned `-l` myself in the question: one more time I got bitten by the fact that the order of arguments to gcc matter... Thanks!